# Flash, Setting document property to Game

Tags: flash, ide

This marks a new chapter for me asking a question about an entirely different subject that I know nothing about :)

I'm following a book called "Flash Games" and it's not for beginners and I'm a beginner so lots of jargon that I don't know and simple google searches don't come up with anything.

What is the Flash IDE?

Does this author mean the application Adobe Flash to build applications. So that means there is Flex, and Flash Catalyst, and Air IDEs? I don't really treat this like IDEs in terms of programmer but I guess I just don't know.

Next. The author says to set the document property on my file.fla to `Game`. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he means "document class".

Long story short: it's the first AS3 class that will be executed when you run your flash game. The important thing is that it inherits from MovieClip and represents the stage, that is what you see on the screen when you open the FLA. (See more: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_document_class.html or http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash/)

By setting it up to Game the author means that there is a Game.as file in the same folder as the the .fla file (or in any other folder defined as source folder).

...

People use the term Flash IDE when they talk about the builder software (e.g Flash CS4) as opposite to Flash as technology, Flash Player, Flash as content (.swf) etc.

Comment: Thanks, everything checked out.

Answer (score 1):

IDE means Integrated Development Environment. It can be anything. Flash CS5 has/is an IDE, FlashBuilder (built on Eclipse) is an IDE, Eclipse is an IDE, etc. Flash Catalyst is sort of an IDE, but a fairly half-assed one.

In this case, it appears they're talking about the Flash IDE.

There's a panel on the right-hand side which has two tabs, Properties and Library. There are all kinds of settings there, but there's nothing I know of that you can set to "Game." Maybe they are talking about naming the document class from which the code for the game will be contained.